# dbext connection string for sql-server

Tags: sql, vim

I have `dbext` installed into `gVim` - the plugin menu is visible and the help file are accessible; just not helping at the moment!

Suspect it is a connection string problem. I have the following in `_vimrc`:

```
" Microsoft SQL Server
let g:dbext_default_profile_WH = 'type=SQLSRV:user=profileName:passwd=profilePassword:dsnname=SQLOLEDB.1:srvname=imsname'
```

Is this correct?: `dsnname=SQLOLEDB.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my working connection string configuration

`let g:dbext_default_profile_mydb = 'type=SQLSRV:user=sa:passwd=password:srvname=localhost\SQLEXPRESS:dbname=mydb'`

It seems that only difference between two configuration strings DNS part so it might be DNS problem as you mentioned.

Comment: You might want to specify both srvname and host:

    let g:dbext_default_profile_mydb = 'type=SQLSRV:user=sa:passwd=password:srvname=localhost:host=localhost\SQLEXPRESS:dbname=mydb'

since adding the instance name to srvname can cause the name lookup to fail.